# Magento on XAMPP cannot send emails

Tags: magento-1, development, smtp, xampp

Anyone can help me set it up so that I can send order emails?

I have already tried configuring an extension SMTP Pro with my gmail account and the test works, but when I try sending an order email, it just notifies me that its already sent. but I don't receive any emails.

Comment: Try using mandrill .
It is a wonderfull extension which can send email even from localhost

Comment: You can use Magepal's GmailSmtpApp extension to send emails from localhost. Here is the link : https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send email from localhost with minimum configuration.

Please check below steps to send an email from localhost.

In the sendmail.ini file (C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini), make the following changes:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587 (some recommend using smtp_port=25 but for me 587 worked)
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=myemail@gmail.com
auth_password=yourgmailpassword
force_sender=myemail@gmail.com

Next, make the following change in your php.ini (C:\xampp\php\php.ini) file:

sendmail_path = “\”C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\” -t”
```

t's very easy to configure php.ini for sending e-mails from your server.You just need to configure php.ini and sendmail.ini correctly.

First you have to configure sendmail_path in your php.ini file it should have to point to executable sendmail file with proper flags

for example , ;sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t" (which is already in your php.ini file need to just remove comment) and other assignments to sendmail_path need to be commented.

after configuring php.ini file you need to configure sendmail.ini file ,in that

first smtp_server=mail.gmail.com (as you want to use gmail as smtp server), second smtp_port=465 (if not worked try 587), third auth_username= yourid@gmail.com auth_password=yourpassword

after this restart your server.

**I hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 1):

from magento1.9 order email goes through cronjob But as you so you need to add cron.sh or cron.php file in your crontab or scheduler(in windows)

For That Smtp pro extension goto below setting and update that and order email works

Go to system->configuration->Aschroder Extensions->Smtp pro-> Queue Configuration->Queue Usage set it to never and your order email goes directly

Hope this will help you